# How to print a certain element in each list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm coding in haskell and want to know how find a certain element in mutiple list.

Here an example let say:

```
x = [(1,2,3,4,5),
      (3,4,5,6,6),
      (5,6,2,1,1),
      (1,2,5,6,2)];
```

Let say I want to find the 3rd element of each list.

So the program will print out 4,6,1,6

I know about the !! but when I do something like x !! 3, it prints out the third row(1,2,5,6,2).

I want it so it print out the 3rd element of each list.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to have a list of lists? Right now, you have a list of tuples. That aside, there is no generic way in Haskell for extracting elements from tuples given and index. The best you can do there is `map (\(_,_,_,e,_) -> e) x`.

Comment: so `x !! 3` will get the third index of `x`, not the third index of each element of `x`?  How do you apply a function to each element of a list?

Comment: @Alec theres no way to go like through each list and get a certain element?

Comment: @ShawnSmith There is a way to go through _lists_ to get a certain element (it's the `(!!)` operator you already found), but you have a list of tuples. Note the difference between `(1,2,3,4,5)` and `[1,2,3,4,5]` (try checking out their types in GHCi).

Comment: @Alec the data I was supplied with was basically like the only I have in the question. It a big list, I just shortened it. Maybe there no way to get that certain element but can we check if let say 6 is in element 3?

Comment: @ShawnSmith Is the list you got exactly as you printed it. Or was it perhaps something like [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]...]?

Comment: And even if we have a list of tuples, we *can* access the third element of each, but only by manual pattern matching as @Alec mentioned above.

Comment: @mnoronha it exactly how its printed. and with what alec posted above, what does the  e mean and how would I use it in my question.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own `Data.Tuple.Select` has all the tuple element selectors you may need.

Comment: Note that you may need to install the `tuple` library to get the `Data.Tuple.Select` module.

Answer (score 7):

What you've provided is not actually a list of lists, but a list of tuples. Tuples have a special type based on the number and type of their elements, so the type of your `x` above is `[(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)]`.

Unlike lists, which allow us to extract values by index with the `!!` operator (ex. `[1,2,3] !! 1 = 2`), in order to extract specific values from a tuple we must pattern match the entire tuple, giving some name to the value we wish to extract and using it in our return value. To extract the fourth value from a tuple of holding 5 values, we could write a function like this:

```
f (a,b,c,d,e) = d
```

Or, as an anonymous function (because, if we are only going to use it when mapping over the list, it's nice to not bother assigning it a name):

```
(\(a,b,c,d,e) -> d)
```

Since we only care about the fourth value, we can choose to discard all others (you said third but meant index 3 -> 4th term above?):

```
(\(_,_,_,x,_) -> x)
```

Now we have a list of such tuples, and we'll want to apply it to each. We can do this with `map`, which will apply the function to each and return a list of the third value from each tuple:

```
f xs = map (\(_,_,_,x,_) -> x) xs
```

Or, with eta-reduction:

```
f = map (\(_,_,_,x,_) -> x)
```

Example usage:

```
gchi>> f [(1,2,3,4,5),(3,4,5,6,6),(5,6,2,1,1),(1,2,5,6,2)]
[4,6,1,6]
```